# What is the proper syntax for `!current_user`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am writing this statement here :

```
where :commentable_id => comments.map(&:id), :user_id => !current_user
```

The problem is it's returning only a user with the id of 0. Assuming this is a non-user, or more specifically a !user.

In this case, I am just trying to say **anybody but the current user**.

How would you write that?

Using `"not #{current_user.id}` returns :

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."user_id" = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, I've written this in the other answer I gave.

The problem is that hashes in conditions are only good for making `==` or `IN` comparisons in SQL. You cannot do bigger or smaller comparisons or not-equals. You have to write a snippet of SQL yourself.

```
where(:commentable_id => comments.map(&:id)).where("user_id != ?", current_user.id)
```

You approach doesn't work, because it will send the results of `!current_user` to the SQL generator (which is the ARel gem). According to Ruby logic, any object that isn't `nil` or `false` is considered to be `true`. When you place a "bang" (exclamation mark) before it, it will make if `false`. And ARel will try to convert false in to whatever database understands as false. Most databases don't understand booleans and they use different other methods for that. SQLite uses `'t'` and `'f'`, and MySQL uses 1 and 0 (I believe).

Answer (score 2):

```
where :commentable_id => comments.map(&:id), :user_id => "<> #{current_user.id}"
```

This will do it.

Comment: This calls SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."user_id" = 0)